# IronPython for SWIG python interface

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, swig

I have a python interface created via SWIG as a wrapper around some 3d party C/C++ program. I can use it via C# no problem. I am just wondering whether IronPython could make my 'integration life' a bit simpler/seamless. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IronPython can't use the wrappers generated by SWIG. It does support [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) for accessing C/C++, but it really depends on what you need. If you're just calling the Python wrapper from C#, it might be easier to use SWIG to generate C# wrappers and bypass Python altogether.